# Unable to use [square bracket] method in Custom Ruby class?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Composite method from [Design Patterns in Ruby](http://designpatternsinruby.com/). I came across the following code.

The goal is to have a base `Task`; in this case its job is to keep track of time and that's it. There are several specific tasks, for example, `MixTask` that keeps track of how long it takes to mix cake ingredients. Lastly, `CompositeTask` creates array of tasks in `@sub_tasks` and keep track of (add/remove/edit) the tasks.

```
class CompositeTask < Task
    def initialize(name)
        super(name)
        @sub_tasks = []
    end

    def remove_sub_task(task)
        @sub_tasks.delete(task)
    end

    def <<(task)
        @sub_tasks << task
    end

    def []=(index, new_value)
        @sub_tasks[index] = new_value
    end

    def get_time_required
        time = 0.0
        @sub_tasks.each {|task| time += task.get_time_required}
        time
    end
end

class Task
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name) 
        @name = name
    end

    def get_time_required
        0.0
    end
end

class MixTask < Task
    def initialize
        super("Mix that batter up!")
    end

    def get_time_required
        3.0
    end
end
```

My question is on how to use the funny-looking `[]` method in `CompositeTask`. The main purpose is to: edit any specific task in `@sub_task` array and to `get_time_required` of a specific task instead of the sum of time from `@sub_task` array.

How can I run `get_time_required` of `@sub_tasks`'s 0th element?

```
   taskie = CompositeTask.new("example")
=> #<CompositeTask:0x00563a22e5afa8 @name="example", @sub_tasks=[]>
   taskie << MixTask.new
=> [#<MixTask:0x00563a22e5a6e8 @name="Mix that batter up!">]
   taskie << MixTask.new
=> [#<MixTask:0x00563a22e5a6e8 @name="Mix that batter up!">, #<MixTask:0x00563a22e59e50 @name="Mix that batter up!">]
   taskie.get_time_required #total time required
=> 6.0
```

I can edit the nth element just fine:

```
taskie[1] = AddDryIngredientsTask.new #edits the 2nd array element successfully 
=> #<AddDryIngredientsTask:0x00563a22da26d8 @name="Add dry ingredients">
   taskie
=> #<CompositeTask:0x00563a22e5afa8 @name="example", @sub_tasks=[#<MixTask:0x00563a22e5a6e8 @name="Mix that batter up!">, #<AddDryIngredientsTask:0x00563a22da26d8 @name="Add dry ingredients">]>
```

However, when I try to look up for specific array element, it returns error:

```
   taskie[1].get_time_required
undefined method `[]' for #<CompositeTask:0x00563a22e5afa8>
   puts(taskie[1].get_time_required)
undefined method `[]' for #<CompositeTask:0x00563a22e5afa8>
   taskie[1]
undefined method `[]' for #<CompositeTask:0x00563a22e5afa8>
```

Here is my question: After appending 2 elements into `@sub_tasks` array, how can I look up `get_time_required` the nth array element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a `[]` method as well (in addition to `[]=`).

```
class CompositeTask < Task
  def [](index)
    @sub_tasks[index]
  end
end
```